# React useCallback() function in Parent is only working fine with Child if React.memo is used, without it not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, memo, usecallback

**Parent Component**

> The parent component contains input which on change sets the state "local" and a button which on click takes this "local" state's value and sets it to "sendLocal"

**Functions**

1. changehandler : triggers on input type change.
2. sendLocalValue : takes "local" value puts it into "sendLocal" variable triggers on button click.
3. sendValue : this memoized function with dependeny "sendLocal" is passed on as a prop in child component triggers once the child is rendered.

   ```
   import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
   import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

   function ParentComponent() {
     const [local, setLocal] = useState();
     const [sendLocal, setsendLocal] = useState();

     const changehandler = (e) => {
       console.log("parent");
       setLocal(e.target.value);
     };

   const sendLocalValue = () => {
           setsendLocal(local);
         };

     const sendValue = useCallback(() => {
       return sendLocal;
     }, [sendLocal]);



     return (
       <>
         <input type="text" onChange={changehandler} defaultValue={local} />
         <button onClick={sendLocalValue}>send</button>
         <ChildComponent getValue={sendValue} />
       </>
     );
   }

   export default ParentComponent;
   ```

**Child Component**

> getValue prop calls the *memoized*  "sendValue" function of parent which returns the value of sendLocal.

**Problem**

> Everything works fine,the child component renders only when the "sendLocal" value changes on button click but if i remove React.memo() in child both the component render on input type change even with useCallback() used, **why**?

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function ChildComponent({ getValue }) {
      console.log("child");
    
      return <div>child's {getValue()}</div>;
    }

export default React.memo(ChildComponent);
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what is not working, both `useCallback` and `React.memo` are useless in this case, as `getValue`/`sendValue` change on every render.

Comment: i'll appreciate the effort if you try it out without it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general misconception that React components rerender when props or state change. while this is partially true, can lead to misunderstoods: a react component rerenders when its state changes or when its parent rerenders (because its state changed or because its parent rerendered, and so on).

So this means that every time `ParentComponent` rerenders, all its (non memoized) children will rerender.

To avoid this, you can use `React.memo` or `React.PureComponent`.

You can verify that by removing `React.memo` and not passing any props to the ChildComponent. Even with no props, it will rerender every time its parent rerenders.

Comment: so you're saying i must use React.memo for there is to be a memoized function? or can i not use useCallback() without it?

Comment: A component can also re-render when a context provider it consumes re-renders.

Comment: @fahadsaleem if you want to prevent ChildComponent from rerendering, then yes you need to use React.memo + React.useCallback to memoize the function.

Answer (score 0):

when the parent re-renders, the whole props object for the child is created as a new object, which leads to the child re-render.
it does not matter that you have memoized all the different individual props, you have to memoize the component itself so that it does not re-render when the whole props object changes.

In this case, it also means that you still have to memoize the function as well as the child component, because React.memo only does a shallow comparison of individual props.